# Round to the nearest N number

Tags: excel, ms-access, vbscript, ms-access-2007, excel-2007

I have a set of decimal numbers, and I need to round them to the nearest number ending in 7.

Ex:

```
0.45 --> 0.47
4.70 --> 4.67
6.49 --> 6.47
8.32 --> 8.37
```

I can use either Excel or Access for this (basically VBS).

I can live with just grabbing the 2 decimal places, converting that to an integer (*100), then applying the rounding rules and then pre-pending the integer value of the original value.

Ex:

```
0.45 --> 45 --> 47 --> 0.47
4.70 --> 70 --> 67 --> 4.67
6.49 --> 49 --> 47 --> 6.47
8.32 --> 32 --> 37 --> 8.37
```

I've tried the rounding formula:

```
Let N represent the nearest number to round to.
Let X represent the input number.
output = ROUND(X / N, 0) * N
```

However this does not give expected results.

Ex:

```
0.45 --> ROUND(45 / 7, 0) * 7 --> 42 != 47
4.70 --> ROUND(70 / 7, 0) * 7 --> 70 != 67
6.49 --> ROUND(49 / 7, 0) * 7 --> 49 != 47
8.32 --> ROUND(32 / 7, 0) * 7 --> 28 != 37
```

How can I round to the nearest number ending in 7?

Comment: Just to clarify, shouldn't 8.32 be rounded *down* since it's 5 units above 8.27? (keiv's formula rounds 8.32 up, which is what I would expect it to be).

Comment: @Jerry yes you are correct. Was a quick-head-math type-o ;-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can round only to zero. So you need to transform the number in such a way that 0.07 is 0.00. For example you can add 0.03 or subtract 0.07. Then after rounding you do the opposite (subtract 0.03 or add 0.07) and get the number you want.

The code:

```
=ROUND(A1+0.03, 1) - 0.03
```